# Creating an RNN with Keras Python

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to machine learning and Keras. I made an Neural Network with Keras for regression looking like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(57, input_dim=44, kernel_initializer='normal', 
activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(45, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(35, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

My data has 44 dimensions, so could you please give me an example how could i make an RNN. I'm trying like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(44, input_shape=(6900, 44), ))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mape', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
```

But i get this error: 
Error when checking input: expected lstm_13_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6900, 44)

Comment: RNNs are used for processing sequence-like data, like words in sentences, timeseries of weather temperature, genomes sequences, musical notes, etc. All of these are examples of sequences. So first you should have a sequence-like data. What is the data you are working on?

Comment: my data looks like this: https://scontent.fskp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/40159383_10204721730878434_598395145989128192_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeEYA4Nb3gomElC9qt0kF6Ou86P7jidco_LeHxEkmCB0-oVA9YKVe9VAh41SF25YomKTqKdkS96E18-sTCBidxJdbml4OV7FvFuAOWxI4mRafQ&oh=e81f4f56ebdf15e9c6eefbb078b8a982&oe=5BFD4157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you, your data is `44` dimensional and not a time series. An `RNN` is computing operations on a sequence of data, i.e. a `2D` and not a `1D` tensor. But you can still use a `RNN` for `1D` vectors, by interpreting them not as one `n`-dimensional vector but as a time series of `n` steps, each containing a `1D` vector.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((-1, 1)
model.add(LSTM(44, input_shape=(6900, 44), ))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mape', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
```

Comment: This works awesome thank you very much.
My data before preprocesing looks like this:

https://scontent.fskp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/40159383_10204721730878434_598395145989128192_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeEYA4Nb3gomElC9qt0kF6Ou86P7jidco_LeHxEkmCB0-oVA9YKVe9VAh41SF25YomKTqKdkS96E18-sTCBidxJdbml4OV7FvFuAOWxI4mRafQ&oh=e81f4f56ebdf15e9c6eefbb078b8a982&oe=5BFD4157

So i guess is a time series, should i continue with the model you gave me or make some changes to it?

Comment: As your data is really a proper time series, you should make changes. Your input data is a sequence of 14-dimensional data and your target series is one dimensional. Therefore, my answer above does not really help you... Take a look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), maybe this helps you out.

Comment: Yes I saw this example, but i couldn't understand how should I change my data because here it shows X with 2 dimensions and i have 49 after preprocesed data